# Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply multiprocessing in the simplest way in Python 3 but it does not work on my laptop. I am using Windows.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

# a dummy function
def f(x):
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('some text',))
    p.start()
    p.join()

print('Done')
```

It did not end as it was expected. Instead, I got this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
> File "<ipython-input-2-46a0e604292b>", line 1, in <module>
> runfile('C:/Users/Mahdi/Mahdi Code/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mahdi/Mahdi Code')
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
> pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
> exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
> File "C:/Users/Mahdi/Mahdi Code/test.py", line 25, in <module>
> p.start()
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
> self._popen = self._Popen(self)
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
> return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
> return Popen(process_obj)
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
> reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
> ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x00000218267C3D30>: attribute lookup f on __main__ failed
> Done
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
> exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
> File "C:\Users\Mahdi\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
> self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
> EOFError: Ran out of input
> ```

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Don't run it in IPython/interactive shell.

Answer (score 5):

some interactive IDEs don't support multiprocessing such as jupyter lab, there are tricks around this involving non-standard multiprocessing modules, but the most straight-forward solution is to not use an interactive environment for multiprocessed code, and instead run python in script mode using VsCode or Pycharm or through the terminal. (Spyder also works but you have to run the code as a script)

Comment: Thanks,
I am using Pycharm. Can this be something in the settings?

Comment: @MahdiHaqverdi don't run it using "Run file in python console" and instead run it using "Run somefile" command. (the one with the green play button image)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same code via the Terminal or Pycharm. I haven't checked other IDE's.

It ran fine on the terminal and the output is

```
some text
Done
```